# Django check if time is available in slot using models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

How would I check if a time that I specify is within 1 hour of any of the orders' times by user 1. Example: I specify a time and post it to an endpoint, the endpoint checks if the giver time is within an hour of any of the other orders with User 1. How would I check if the time is within 1 hour of any of teh order models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use range, so you will get `Order` between 2 datetime :

```py
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
specific_time = timezone.now()
# i am not sure if you want in range `timedelta` - 1 h and `timedelta` + 1 h 
# but it's easy to modify
order_range = (specific_time - datetime.timedelta(hour=1), specific_time)
orders_in_range = Order.objects.filter(time__range=order_range)
```

Comment: SOrry to clarify, I want to make sure that the user specified time is not within 1 hour of any of the order models time fields.

Comment: just override save method and do a `exists()` so you can raise an error